# Try to find the ratio of two arcs

Tags: triangles, circles, arc-length

O1 is the center of the big circle; O2 is the center of the small one.

Line(O2-P) is vertical to line(A-C).

Line(PQ):line(PB)=2:7

What's the ratio of arc(AC) and arc(CB)?

[image]

Comment: Hint: $AC:CB=AP:PO_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $PQ=2$ and $PB=7$: by Pythagoras' theorem we then get $BQ=\sqrt{53}$.

If $PH$ is an altitude of triangle $BPQ$, then: 
$$PH=PQ\cdot {PB\over BQ}={14\over\sqrt{53}}$$ 
and by similarity: 
$$QH={4\over\sqrt{53}}, 
\quad BH={49\over\sqrt{53}},
\quad HO_2=QO_2-QH={45\over 2\sqrt{53}}.
$$ 
Triangle $APH$ is similar to $PHO_2$, hence: 
$$
AH={392\over45\sqrt{53}},\quad 
AO_2=AH+HO_2={53\sqrt{53}\over90}
\quad\text{and}\quad 
PA={14\sqrt{53}\over45}.
$$ 
Finally, $ABC$ is similar to $APO_2$ and 
$\displaystyle AB=AO_2+BO_2={49\sqrt{53}\over45}$, whence: 
$$
BC={49\over\sqrt{53}}, \quad AC={1372\over45\sqrt{53}}.
$$
It follows that:
$$
{AC\over BC}={28\over45},
\quad\text{and}\quad
{\text{arc}(AC)\over \text{arc}(BC)}={\arctan(28/45)\over\arctan(45/28)}.
$$